# Resizing browser causes divs to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to make a parallax scrolling website and its template is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="container1"></div>
  <div id="container2"></div>
  <div id="container3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
  height:auto
}

#container1, #container2, #container3 {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#container1 {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
#container2 {
  background-color:#000;
}
#container3 {
  background-color:#363636;
}
```

**Problem:** If you scroll down to either #container2 or #container3 and resize the browser, the website appears to scroll.

I suspect that the height:100%; is causing issue. In particular, resizing causes all three containers to resize, creating a weird offset.

**Things I have tried:**

- Binding the resize event and dynamically changing the height of the divs
- Adding a min-height property so that the resize locks after resizing
- Hiding the div that is no longer in the view

Is there any simple way of fixing this? The last attempt fixes it, but I feel like there should be a better way rather cluttering my JS file with several .hide() and .show() events.

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to achieve. Should each section be 100% height and width?  Changing #content to height: 100%; will achieve this. http://jsfiddle.net/AL739/

Comment: What is your #content 100% the height of ?

Comment: @dwreck08 Thanks for the fiddle. That's the layout I have. But what I'm trying to fix is the window resize issue. When you resize vertically, the divs move, making it appear like it is scrolling. I'm trying to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Also @dwreck08, your jsfiddle has the same issue.